# How to set Allowed_Types to protect this query from another type exstention file

Tags: excel, codeigniter, input

I have a query to upload files. the file is an xlsx / xlsx / (ms.excel) file extension. I don't know where I have to put "file allowed type".

if an xlsx / xls / (ms excel extension) non-file file cannot be inputted
 Please help

```
public function proses_upload()
{

  $file_upload = array();
  $jumlah = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
  for ($i=0; $i < $jumlah; $i++) { 

    $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $file_upload[$i] = '';
    if($file_name != ''){
        $explode = explode('.',$file_name);
        $ekstensi = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $bulan = date('M');
        $tahun = date('y') ;
        $kode  = $this->session->userdata('kode_puskesmas');
        $new_file_name =$explode[1].'_'.$kode.'_'.$bulan.$tahun.'.'.$ekstensi;
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];  
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "file/file_PTM/".$new_file_name);
        $file_upload[$i] = $new_file_name;  

        }
    }

                $nama_file1 = $file_upload[0];
                $format_p2ptm =1; 
                $tanggal = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $jenis ='p2ptm';



                if (!$nama_file1 == "") {
                    $this->app_model->insert_data('penyakit', $format_p2ptm, $tanggal,$nama_file1,$jenis, $this->session->userdata('id_puskesmas'));
```

Comment: Are you uploading files?

Comment: yes. multiple upload file

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload multiple files like this

Add path according to your directory

```
for ($i=0; $i < $jumlah; $i++) { 

    $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $file_upload[$i] = '';
    if($file_name != ''){

        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];

        $config['upload_path'] = '.file/file_PTM/'.$new_file_name;
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'xlsx|csv|xls';
        $config['max_size']             = 1000;
        $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        $config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
             //image uploading error   
        }else{
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_name = $data['file_name'];
            $ekstensi = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $explode = explode('.',$file_name);
            $bulan = date('M');
            $tahun = date('y') ;
            $kode  = $this->session->userdata('kode_puskesmas');

            $new_file_name =$explode[1].'_'.$kode.'_'.$bulan.$tahun.'.'.$ekstensi;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: but this upload is multiple upload . if i use this library upload its still work ?

Comment: I think the file path is the issue. What is the path of the directory where you are uploading the images